# Primeng Turbo table is not rendered as expected in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I would Create a dynamic table using primeng.

When I load my app turbo table is empty, but when I click on pagination button or header data is rendered.

```
<div class="">
  <p-table #tt  [value]="files" selectionMode="single" sortMode="single"  [(selection)]="selectedUser" dataKey="name" [globalFilterFields]="['uid','firstName','lastName']" (onRowSelect)="selectedUserDetails($event)" styleClass="tab-result" [paginator]="true" [rows]="10"  [first]="first">
          <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
          <div style="text-align: right">        
                  <i class="fa fa-search" style="margin:4px 4px 0 0"></i>
                  <input type="text" pInputText size="50" placeholder="Global Filter" (input)="tt.filterGlobal($event.target.value, 'contains')" style="width:auto">
          </div>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                  <tr >
                          <th *ngFor="let col of cols" [pSortableColumn]="col.field" >{{col.header}}
                                  <p-sortIcon [field]="col.field"></p-sortIcon>   
                          </th>
                    </tr>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-file>
                  <tr [pSelectableRow]="file">
                          <td *ngFor="let col of cols"> {{file[col.field]}}</td>
                  </tr>
          </ng-template>
  </p-table>
</div>
```

**TS file**

```
export class DataTableComponent implements OnInit {
  cols;
  files;
  constructor(private creditPointService: CreditPointService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("test");
    this.cols = [
      { field: "name", header: "Name" },
      { field: "scope", header: "First Name" },
      { field: "finalDecisionDate", header: "Final Decision Date" },
      { field: "typeOfRequest", header: "Type Of Request" }
    ];
    this.files=this.creditPointService.getResults();
    console.log(this.files)
   /* this.creditPointService.getResults().toPromise().then(
      data => {
        console.log("la data", data);
        var test = data;
        this.files = test;
      },
       err => {
         console.log(err);
       }
    );*/ Service should handle getting data in real example
  }
}
```

every time to show data I should click on pagination or on header items but the expected behavior is showing data after app in loaded.

Here's a [stackblitz reproduction](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-turbo-table-hk6axc?file=app%2Fdata-table%2Fdata-table.component.ts)